# Anonymous login using OpenID or OAuth

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, registration, anonymous

**In short:** Can I use OpenID oder OAuth for anonymous logins on my web service?

**Described in more detail:**

*Scenario/Background:* I'm going to provide online-tools for mental health related exercises. The users should be able to see their completed exercises after each login, but I don't want them to register at my service—because I don't want to store their e-mail adresses, passwords, not even nicknames or anything like that (not even hashed!), because it could reveal the users' identities. I want to keep their privacy perfectly safe by not storing anything that relates to the offline identity.

*Problem:* How to perform the login (or how to recognize recurring users) without credentials?

*Approach(?):* When I use my Google account to log in at some third-party web services, I'm asked wether I want to share my profile data, e-mail adress—and what else. Would it here be possible to reveal nothing? The only thing, the service would know, is that somebody has a google account and knows the password. To me, it's completely unimportant *who* the owner is, it's just important to recognize the same owner after each login—let's say by some kind of anonymous token id.

- Is this approach working?
- Are there other approaches for anonymous user logins—without storing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/). OpenID Connect is a specification built on top of OAuth 2.0 ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)). You can delegate user authentication to an Identity Provider (such as Google) that supports OpenID Connect.

An IdP will issue an [ID token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) to you after successful user authentication. You can find the user's attributes such as name, email address, etc. in the ID token. So, you don't have to manage users' attributes any more if you use an external Identity Provider that supports OpenID Connect.

---

<sup>(Addition for the comment)</sup>

[OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) has defined 6 standard scopes as listed below. These values can be included in `scope` parameter of an authorization request.

1. `openid`
2. `profile`
3. `email`
4. `address`
5. `phone`
6. `offline_access`

Among the above, `profile`, `email`, `address` and `phone` are defined in "[5.4. Requesting Claims using Scope Values](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims)". They can be used to request some attributes of a user to be included in an [ID token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) which will be issued by an authorization server. For example, when `email` is included in `scope` parameter, the ID token issued based on the request will contain values of `email` and `email_verified` (if the authorization server supports the attributes).

So, if you want to minimize the number of attributes contained in an ID token, avoid including `profile`, `email`, `address` and `phone` in `scope` parameter. In other words, `scope` parameter should contain only `openid`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This sounds helpful. Is it possible, that name and email adress are **NOT** transmitted at all? If the users remain completely anonymous, it's easier for them to trust the system.

Comment: @TimoStolz Did you build the system? I am actually looking to do a survey of systems that have some privacy restrictions similar to yours. It would be great if your system is up and you can share some implementation/architecture details.